# Insert with Python into InfluxDb error: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

When I run a Python client to insert data into InfluxDb with a specific timestamp it returns this error: *'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'*.
I found something on github that defines method `total_seconds()` into some `timeutils.py` file. Here is the code:

```
from datetime import datetime

def total_seconds(td):
    # Keep backward compatibility with Python 2.6 which doesn't have
    # this method
    if hasattr(td, 'total_seconds'):
        return td.total_seconds()
    else:
        return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6

def convert_to_epoch(timestamp):
    diff = (timestamp - datetime(1970, 1, 1))
    seconds = int(diff.total_seconds())
    seconds = int(total_seconds(diff))
    return seconds
```

I can't find timeutils.py. Python version is 2.6 and I cannot update to 2.7. Where should I add that function to make client work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just add it to the same file where the error occurs. It's an independent function, not a class method, so you will have to change the calling line from

```
seconds = int(diff.total_seconds())
```

to

```
seconds = int(total_seconds(diff))
```

or something similar.